# How to set back to specific tab from activity android, using onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

i'm using TabLayout and viewpager for swipe between each tab, and i have problem at positioning tabs, ex: im at tabs3 and click something & go to new activity which is detail of something, and my problems is when i want go back to specific on tabs3, but not back to tabs3 and its direct back to tabs1, and i already search but still not get solve.

how to back from activity to specific tabs which is in tab using fragment..?

i'm using this for the first calling TabFragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
NavigationView mNavigationView;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }



    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TabFragment()).commit();

}}
```

and thenn, this is how i setting tabs.

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_items = 4 ;
public static Toolbar toolbar;

private int[] icons_off = {
        R.mipmap.ic_panorama_white_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_notifications_active_white_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_inbox_white_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_tag_faces_white_36dp
};
private int[] icons_on = {
        R.mipmap.ic_panorama_black_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_notifications_active_black_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_inbox_black_36dp,
        R.mipmap.ic_tag_faces_black_36dp
};

private String[] title_tab = {
        "",
        "Tour",
        "Draft",
        "My Profile"
};

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
    View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


    toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) x.findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_landscape_white_36dp);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(icons_on[0]).select();
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(icons_off[1]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(icons_off[2]);
            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(icons_off[3]);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_landscape_white_36dp);
                            toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>"+title_tab[position]+"</font>"));
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(icons_on[0]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(icons_off[1]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(icons_off[2]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(icons_off[3]);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            toolbar.setLogo(null);
                            toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>"+title_tab[position]+"</font>"));
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(icons_off[0]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(icons_on[1]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(icons_off[2]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(icons_off[3]);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            toolbar.setLogo(null);
                            toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>"+title_tab[position]+"</font>"));
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(icons_off[0]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(icons_off[1]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(icons_on[2]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(icons_off[3]);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            toolbar.setLogo(null);
                            toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>"+title_tab[position]+"</font>"));
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(icons_off[0]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(icons_off[1]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(icons_off[2]);
                            tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(icons_on[3]);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                }

            });


        }
    });

    return x;

}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Chat Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(in);
    } else if(id == R.id.action_setting){
        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Chat Clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        startActivity(in);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position){
            case 0 : return new Feed();
            case 1 : return new Tour();
            case 2 : return new Project();
            case 3 : return new MyProfile();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_items;

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        /*
        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                return "Primary";
            case 1 :
                return "Social";
            case 2 :
                return "Updates";
            case 3 :
                return "User";
        }
        */
        return null;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

}}
```

and my last position before back to what i want.

```
    public class TourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        // here's where i want to back to specific tab
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you create the new activity, save the viewpager position, after that, when you navigate back, set the position to the view pager with `setCurrentItem(position);`

First, save your position before you start the other activity, it can be a sharedPreferences or something else.

Secondly, at the tab fragment'a onResume read the position from sharedPreferences and set the current item to the viewpager with viewpager.setCurrentItem(position).

Comment: i still dont get it, please tell me how that's step working with my code?

Comment: yeahh, thanks it works, i'm using sharedPreferences too.

Answer (score 1):

try adding finish() when back button is pressed in the called activity. When we call one activity from other activity, the caller activity's instance state is saved so you fragment will be saved in stack and then called activity will be called so if you wish to go back then just finish the first activity and the caller activity's instance state will be called and you will get the same fragment from which you had called the called activity. So add this code in called activity:

```
@Override onBackPressed{finish();}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save the current fragment position when navigating to the other activity, and when returning to the first activity on onResume() set 
viewpager.setCurrentItem(int index) where index is the value you saved.

Comment: how step are you using, i still dont get it, please tell me flow are you using with my code above..?